# Magento Product not saving from admin

Tags: php

everyone,

I have a website in magento. currently i have issue in backend product not updating values when we click's on save and continue button it's loading but not updating values and success message also not coming it will happen for some products if custom option having lot means it happen. iam using Magento ver. 1.9.3.1

Please help me anyone.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Whats the error? Open firebug and see the error or see magento system log for error.

Comment: May be the issue related to max_input_vars =  in PHP.ini please check this setting in it.

Comment: i have reviewed max_input_vars it has 1200000.

Comment: Any one please help me.